# Border-radius rendering funny

Tags: html, image, css

I'm developing a site for mobile. Users have profile pictures that should have rounded edges, similar to twitter. However, on the smaller images, only some of the corners are being affected, even though the same images look perfect at the top of the page.

My page is here:
http://porndoraone.com/finnaRoot/index.php

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want rounded images ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the padding-left and padding-top.  They change the overall width and height of the element and where the border is, change them to margins and you'll be fine:

```
.userpostpics{
    width:150px; 
    height:150px; 
    border-radius: 15px; 
    margin:10px; 
    float:left; 
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your **CSS** change

```
.userpostpics {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 19px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

to

```
.userpostpics {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 19px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Hope this will help you ..

Answer (score 1):

```
.userpostpics {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px; /* Use margin- instead */
    margin-top: 20px;  /* of padding- */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add border raduis with 50% like here :

```
.userpics {
    width: 190px;
    height: 190px;
    margin: 2px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

img.friendpics {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 2px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```